# Powershell script to colour particular cell of an XLSX file when particular condition met

Tags: powershell

I am generating a report in CSV file using powershell. I want to change the colour of particular cell of CSV file if satisfies particular condition how can I do it using powershell.

Comment: You cannot colour a `.CSV`, I think you mean `.XLSX`.

Comment: Yes. How can I do it with .xlsx

Answer (score 0):

There is a property .Interior.ColorIndex yo set the color of an excel cell.

```
$Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

Docs: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/highlight-the-active-cell-row-or-column&ved=2ahUKEwjr18zrjoXoAhX7wjgGHaPJAsgQFjALegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw0nO29xwXGwsQOvHO8O5Fhd